# What is the difference between RDF2vec and other knowledge graph embeddings methods(foreg: ComplEx, TransE, Pykeen etc)?

Tags: python, rdf, knowledge-graph

I would like to know which knowledge graph embeddings method I should use. I am a little confused about the embeddings methods available. Currently, I am using RDf2vec for generating embeddings from RDF triples. But how do these other methods such as TransE, CompIEx, Pykeen differ from RDf2vec? Can anyone make it clear?

Comment: just check the papers/explanations/docs for each ? then you would probably know how they differ.

Comment: Yes, I checked. like we can calculate hit@ , MRR score, and other metrics by transE, compIEx, etc as they also require hyperparameters to train the model to generate embeddings. But I did not see such metrics that we calculate by Rdf2Vec. So  I get a little confused whether the embeddings generated by all these methods are correct or the same for further use?

Comment: what means "correct"? There is no correctness measure, you should read again what embeddings are. and rdf2vec vs TransE are totally different approaches, one uses random walks the other neural networks with a translation based method. And Pykeen? This is just a framework which wraps plenty of those approaches and makes them easy to use. Honestly, I really sugest to read one of the dozens of survey papers for KG embeddings - maybe this will help you as you're lacking fundamental stuff (which isn't bad, everybody starts from scratch, but it will help you maybe)

Comment: and with correctness, I meant that Hits@K, mean rank, These indexes are often used to measure the embedding quality of a model which can be possible by neural network-based embeddings.